# OpenMP private class instance variable

Tags: c++, openmp

I am using OpenMP and I am making variables as private in Windows VC++ 13. These variables are class instances. The class is a complex class with pointers, instance of other class, nested and deep. Can I be sure that everything is properly given to the private copies of the threads?

Also I am not able to make a class instance private, it wont link, it says

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ClassName::ClassName(void)" (??0ClassName@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function ...
```

Comment: Fortunately your specific question is easy to answer. However, please keep in mind that questions should always include a [mcve] and adding one would also improve this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are declared `private`, are **not private copies**. It's initial value is *as if it had been locally declared without an initializer*. So for a `class`, it is default constructed. The standard explicitly requires

```
A variable of class type (or array thereof) that appears in a private clause requires an accessible, unambiguous default constructor for the class type.
```

Your error message is just telling you that it is missing.

Maybe you are confusing `private` with `firstprivate`, which actually initializes from the original value outside of the parallel region. For those, you need a copy constructor. The correctness of your code will depend on that copy constructor being implemented properly.